# Unique function: looping through variables in R

Tags: r, loops

I am currently in a loop in my R code and I want to use the following code:

```
distinct.values <- unique(SQL_Table$column.names2[for.num])
```

column.names2 looks like this

```
column.names2
[1] "plan"           "gender"         "marital_status" "acceleration"   "extension"     
[6] "inflation"
```

depending on the `for.num` I want a different variable after the $.

Example:
 when `for.num` = 1.

I want `distinct.values` to be set as `unique(SQL_Table$plan)`

when `for.num` = 2.

I want `distinct.values` to be set as `unique(SQL_Table$gender)`

and so on...

How can I do this?

Comment: You probably want `unique(SQL_Table[[column.names2[for.num]]])`. Note that use of `[[ ]]` indexing instead of `$`.

Comment: @jdobres that solved the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand my comment on the original question, there a few different ways to access columns of data frames.

```
my_df$column_name
```

When using the `$` operator, "column_name" is specified as a literal token in the R script. Note that because the column name is unquoted, this method does not allow variable substitution.

```
my_df[["column_name"]]
```

When using the `[[ ]]` operator, a string (or vector of strings) is expected. In this case, variable substitution is allowed, so the following is valid:

```
my_col <- "column_name"
my_df[[my_col]]
```

This would be equivalent to `my_df$column_name`.

So your code could be modified to read:

```
unique(SQL_Table[[column.names2[for.num]]])
```